# jQuery Ui Widgets Menu Display all children on hover parent

Tags: jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, submenu

This example from https://jqueryui.com/menu/#default display 1 level submenu on hover `Music`.

How to display all levels submenus on hover `Music` only e.g:
[image]

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Please provide an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please also review the `expand` method: http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#method-expand